# How to query both relational database and ontology (OWL) from a web application?

Tags: database, web, sparql, ontology, knowledge-graph

I have an ontology (.owl file) about the restaurant and I also have two tables of data: customer.csv and orders.csv which are stored in PostgreSQL database.

I want to create a simple web application which can accept SQL queries and transfer it to right SQL sub queries to query data related to customer and orders from PostgreSQL database and SPARQL queries to get info related to restaurant from ontology OWL file.

1. What kind layer I need to prepare to parse user input SQL queries into two parts which will be sent to RDB and Ontology respectively?
2. How do I query my .owl file from my web?

I am very new to this and confused what I need to start with.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What you want is still a research topic and called a federated query engine. To be even more precise, you want to query different datasource, another dimension of heterogeneity. This is called *"Data Lakes"* nowadays - so what you want is a query engine/framework/API for Data Lakes. This would then translate the SQL query into the corresponding query language - e.g., for OWL/RDF this would most likely be SPARQL, for XML it would be XPAth/XQuery ..., for a MongoDB database it would be ..., for ...

Comment: The other way would obviously be to load all your data into the relational database.